# Load a big plist from url in background

Tags: ios, xcode, load, plist, grand-central-dispatch

I load a big plist file from url and I must wait for some seconds before I can use the application. Is there some solution? How it can be loaded in background? Is `GCD` what I need? How it can be implemented?

My code:

```
NSString *urlStr = [[NSString alloc] 
                    initWithFormat:@"http://www.domain.com/data.xml"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new thread to do so
Please check the following

```
//Create the thread 
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadPList) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

- (void) loadPList
{
    //Load the plist
    NSString *urlStr = [[NSString alloc] 
                       initWithFormat:@"http://www.domain.com/data.xml"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    //Update the ui
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Update UI if you have to
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But how can I update mapView? because my annotations doesn't show before I zoom out or something.

Comment: Please post it as a new question, also please up vote the answer and accept it, if it was helpful :)